# Assumptions for machine learning algorithms

Tags: regression, svm, random-forest, normality-assumption

Every machine learning assumes that data has some characteristics like in linear regression, the features should not correlated and the variance in the error is constant, etc.
Is there a reference that summarizes the assumptions of each algorithm or at least the common ones like SVM, neural networks, trees and random forests?

Comment: You can check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/back-to-basics-assumptions-of-common-machine-learning-models-e43c02325535)

Comment: There are so many regressors and classifiers in sklearn. Is there any single place where I can find the basic assumptions for every model in the library?